# Problema con wordpress mail() funcion

Tags: php, linux, wordpress

Hola como estan? Soy nuevo aca asique nada, estoy teniendo un problema con un wordpress que esta alojado en un servidor de digitalocean, el tema es que este wordpress anteriormente estaba alojado en godaddy, con dominio, mail todo lo que este ofrece, despues de varios problemas decidimos migrarnos a digital, con todo lo que esto significa(redireccionar dominios, etc) todo funcionaba perfecto hasta que la administradora del wordpress me dice que tiene un problema con el formulario de contacto, la cosa es que no deja enviar mensajes, estuve chusmeando un poco y encontre que no permitia enviar mensajes porque la funcion mail() de php esta desactivada o algo asi entendi, segui buscando y encontre que instalar sendmail iba a solucionar las cosas, el tema es que se soluciono el tema del error al enviar el mensaje pero el mensaje nunca llega a destino(mail que esta en godaddy) y aca me quede, configure todo segun una guia cambiando el /etc/hosts agregando el dominio de la pagina pero nada, la verdad que ya estoy un poco perdido.

Cualquier ayuda me seria muy util! desde ya muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pueden estar pasando 2 cosas:

- Has configurado tu cuenta de correo que vas a usar como remitente en tu php.ini? El no configurar esto puede ocasionar que el mail que estas mandando sea marcado como spam y no se muestre al destinatario.
- Incluso si todo está bien configurado también pueden estar marcando los emails que envías desde tu servidor como spam y no permiten que lleguen a sus destinatarios. Deberías probar enviando a una cuenta de correo que su filtro de correos spam no sea tan robusta, como una cuenta de correo corporativa, porque gmail, hotmail u otras conocidas si los bloquean.

Cuando hayas verificado que si envia correos tu servidor deberias investigar como configurar tu servidor para que no marque como spam los correos que envias.

Revisa este link:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20396449/php-ini-sendmail-configuration-to-send-an-email-using-a-php-script

O también usar algun servidor SMTP externo con PHP: 
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-gmail-or-yahoo-with-php-mail-function

Suerte.

Comment: Hola, muchas gracias por la info hace un rato lo pude solucionar, los problemas que encontre fueron los siguientes:
1) El archivo /etc/hosts la linea que tenia como ´127.0.0.1 localhost localhost.localdomain midominio.com´
tenia que cambiarlo por ´127.0.0.1 midominio.com localhost´
2) El otro problema era agregar en el php.ini el comando de sendmail:
sendmail -t

Con eso el problema se soluciono!

Answer (score 1):

Otra opción, que siempre recomiendo y de paso liberas procesos del servidor, es que los emails de WordPress se envíen usando SMTP. Hay un plugin estupendo para eso: https://es.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-mail-smtp/